# How To Open Files in Illustrator 2020 via AppleScript

Tags: applescript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

OSX 10.13.6, AI 2020, Applescript Editor Version 2.10 (194), AppleScript 2.7

(Don't think this should matter, but am not prepared to upgrade the OS, as NVidia still hasn't released drivers for the TitanXP GPU the system uses).

Sticking to AppleScript in this discussion.  No "Just Use JavaScript" suggestions please, unless you can confirm or deny that the problem also occurs in JavaScript.

Am wondering if Adobe has made a change to their Illustrator API, as, since upgrading to the new 2020 version, Applescript files that used to work with earlier versions of Illustrator are now having difficulty opening files when referred to by an alias, or a variable in posix-style format.

InDesign does not seem to have been affected, as every time a major version upgrade occurs I run a script on some several hundred .INDD files to prevent the "save-as" dialog next time they are used, which can mess up scripting.  That script still works.  Haven't tried Photoshop yet, but most of the automation I use there is in the form of their internal "Actions".

After a little research, am thinking they may have tinkered with HFS support, resulting in unanticipated consequences.

Illustrator 2020 can open a file referenced by a hard-coded string in posix-style format, but it cannot open that same file from a variable, either an HFS-style alias, or quoted posix-style string, i.e,

```
  set theHFSPath to "Mac HD:Users:Mac User:Documents:Illustrator:myFile.ai"
  set thePosixPath to quoted form of theHFSPath
  # i.e., '/Volumes/Mac HD/Users/Mac User/Documents/Illustrator/myFile.ai'

  Tell Application "Adobe Ilustrator"
    # Opens OK
    open POSIX file "/Volumes/Mac HD/Users/Mac User/Documents/Illustrator/myFile.ai" without dialogs

    # Crashes with "Adobe Illustrator got an error: The specified file could not be opened because it could not be found"
    open theHFSPath as alias without dialogs
    # open (theHFSPath as alias) also crashes

    # Crashes with "Adobe Illustrator got an error: File/Folder expected"
    open POSIX file thePosixPath without dialogs
    # open POSIX file (quoted form of thePosixPath)
    #    without quoting HFSPath above also crashes
  End Tell
```

Am suspecting Adobe maybe dropped a low-level routine that dealt with HFS, and with this routine failing, the open command cannot "see" the file to open it.

Not much on the 'tubes yet, but I have run across:

http://forum.latenightsw.com/t/apple-script-for-illustrator-2020-javascript-code-was-missing/2167

from a little less than a week ago, which seems to be describing the same issue.

Anyone else run across this, or know how to get around it?

Comment: Being that your are running macOS on a Hackintosh, I guess anything can happen.

Comment: A) One can run an external GPU via Thunderbolt.  B) Even if this were a Hackintosh, it would have nothing to do with the new behavior.  Neither the OS or version of Applescript have changed.  Only AI is different.

Comment: 1. “error” != “crash”. 2. `quoted form of theHFSPath` should read `POSIX path of theHFSPath`. 3. Make sure the path points to a valid file. 4. Try moving the `POSIX file` specifier outside the `tell application…` block, e.g. `set f to POSIX file "/Users/foo/myFile.ai" ; tell app "Adobe Illustrator" to open f`.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a crash, not a coding error.  Please see code in the post.  As a hard-coded string in POSIX style, it opens.  As a variable set to the EXACT SAME STRING, it crashes, quoted or not.  As an HFS-style alias, it also crashes.  In AI 2019, it would open OK as an alias (obviously not quoted).  The same code that worked in AI 2019, with the same file, now breaks in AI 2020.

Comment: “Crash” means a process exited abnormally. “Adobe Illustrator got an error: File/Folder expected” is an error; the process is unable to perform the requested operation and tells you so. The distinction is important here because if either Illustrator/Script Editor is crashing then that’s a fatal bug in the application itself—not your fault—which you should file a report on. OTOH, if SE is displaying an error message at the bottom of your script, that’s either a (non-fatal) bug in AI’s `open` handler or a bug in your own AppleScript code. Clarifying crash vs error helps us narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples work exactly as expected on AI 2020 (which I’ve just installed) and CC 2017 running under macOS 10.14.6:

```
set alis to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- an existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open alis
-- AI opens test.ai document

set furl to POSIX file "/Users/foo/test.ai"
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open furl
-- AI opens test.ai document
```

This works as expected too (notwithstanding the awful quality of AI’s error messages):

```
set furl to POSIX file "/Users/foo/xxxxx.ai" -- a non-existent file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open furl
-- SE reports error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

..

However, the following does not work as you’d expect:

```
set pth to "/Users/foo/test.ai"
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open POSIX file pth
```

The `open` command neither opens the file nor sends back an error message explaining why not. This is one of those maddenly quirky and unintuitive gotchas with AppleScript’s object specifiers, made doubly confusing by AI’s lousy error handling.

Short explanation: The script is effectively telling AI to open `POSIX file "…" of <Illustrator>`, and since the app’s dictionary doesn’t include a `POSIX file` class, the app is unable to resolve that reference. Whereas what you need is to first say `POSIX file "…" of <AppleScript>`, which tells AS to build a `POSIX file` value (which it knows how to do) and then pass the constructed value to the `open` command.

This is why it’s always a good idea to build `alias`, `POSIX file`, `date`, etc values outside of any `tell app…` blocks. It’s a crude rule of thumb, but easy to remember. (Best not to think about AS behaviour too hard as you’ll only make your [head hurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons).)

--

Now, if you’re seeing different behaviors under macOS 10.15 then that implies something else has changed (presumably in the OS) which is causing knock-on effects elsewhere; if that’s the case, update your original post with more details.

---

[updated to add]

These work correctly on AI 2020 and earlier (macOS 10.14.6):

```
set f to POSIX file "/Users/foo/test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f
-- AI opens document

set f to POSIX file "/Users/foo/test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f with dialogs
-- AI opens document

set f to POSIX file "/Users/foo/test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f without dialogs
-- AI opens document

set f to POSIX file "/Users/foo/xxxxxx.ai" -- non-existent file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f without dialogs
-- AI throws File Not Found error
```

This also works correctly on AI 2020:

```
set f to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f
```

However, while these work correctly on AI 2019, on AI 2020 they *incorrectly* throw a File Not Found error even though the file exists:

```
set f to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f with dialogs
-- error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: The specified file could not be opened because it could not be found" number 9032

set f to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f without dialogs
-- error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: The specified file could not be opened because it could not be found" number 9032

set f to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open f with options {class:open options, add to recent files:true}
-- error "Adobe Illustrator got an error: The specified file could not be opened because it could not be found" number 9032
```

Therefore, can confirm there is a [non-crashing] BUG in AI 2020’s `open` command that causes it to fail when its direct parameter is an *alias* value *and* one or more positional parameters are also given.

For now, you’ll need to work around this bug by coercing your alias value to a `POSIX file` value[1] prior to passing it to AI 2020’s `open` command:

```
set f to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:foo:test.ai" -- existing file
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to open (f as «class furl») with options {class:open options, add to recent files:true}
```

Alternatively, it may be a good time rework your AppleScript code to eliminate using alias values and use POSIX file values throughout. The ancient (pre-OSX) `alias` value type has long been deprecated throughout the rest of macOS in favor of modern security-scoped bookmarks, which [may be why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_rot) it’s suddenly breaking in a freshly-updated app like AI 2020.

Alas, AppleScript was relegated to maintenance mode some years ago so I doubt Apple will ever sort out its absolute mess of old/new/working/broken file types; they’re just something you’ll need to be aware of and work around in your own code. (i.e. Don’t bother filing an AppleScript feature request with Apple; unless it’s a security hole they’ll likely just ignore it.)

You can if you want file an Adobe bug report on AI 2020’s `open` command. No guarantees they’ll fix it; they may just tell you the same thing—stop passing it [deprecated] alias values and use [supported] POSIX file values instead—but at least it’ll be on the record as WontFix and users can be made aware of it.

--

[1] Note that when coercing a value to POSIX file you *must* write `f as «class furl»`, *not* `f as POSIX file`. This is due to a longstanding defect in AS which Apple are never going to fix.

Comment: (Sorry for the formatting)
Foo, thanks, the examples, alas, did not work.  Tried on multiple machines.
set theFile to "Users:Mac User:Documents:Illustrator:myFile.ai"
(Inside AI Tell)
Fails: open theFile as alias | 
Fails: open POSIX file (POSIX path of theFile) |
Fails: open POSIX file (quoted form of POSIX path of theFile) |
Works: open "/Users/Mac User/Documents/Illustrator/myFile.ai" |
This worked fine in AI 2019, but  AI 2020 does not appear to accept aliases, or references to POSIX paths in variable form.  It only opens them if the POSIX-style reference is hard-coded.

Comment: Also tried setting the vars outside the tell as Foo suggested.  Same response, it fails unless you use a POSIX-style reference in a hard-coded string.

Comment: You need to pay more attention to what the error messages say, because most of them are telling you that your paths are pointing to non-existent files. `"Users:Mac User:Documents:Illustrator:myFile.ai"` is not a valid path (HFS paths start with volume name); therefore all of your subsequent examples using that path will fail. You’re just confusing yourself. First use this to debug the path: `set f to POSIX file "/Users/Mac User/Documents/Illustrator/myFile.ai" ; tell app "Finder" to exists f`; once Finder confirms the path is valid, change it to `tell app "Adobe Illustrator" to open f`.

Answer (score 0):

'k, the issue does not seem to be with regards to HFS or POSIX paths, per se.  I very much appreciate all the replies and comments, and still believe there is a bug in AI 2020's open command; will be heading over to Adobe to see if anyone else has reported it.

It was very confusing that if one hard-coded the path, i.e.,

```
Tell Adobe Illustrator
   open POSIX file "/Users/Mac User/Documents/Illustrator/myFile.ai" without dialogs
End Tell
```

it ***would*** work.

However, turns out that with AI 2020, the culprit is the optional "without dialogs" parameter in conjunction with an alias or POSIX-style variable reference to the file.

According to the dictionary one would append

```
without dialogs
```

to the open command in order to bypass any regular dialogs AI might present when opening the file.

Though this worked fine in AI 2019, it is causing the open command to crash in AI 2020, even though the AI 2020 dictionary still shows "dialogs" as an optional boolean parameter with the same syntax as the 2019 version.

To test this hypothesis, I cranked up an older Mini that still has AI 2019 on it, and tried:

```
set theFile to "Users:Mac User:Documents:Illustrator:myFile.ai"
open theFile as alias without dialogs
```

As expected, this worked just fine, as it has for years.

In AI 2020, with the same file reference,

```
open theFile as alias without dialogs
```

crashes the open command.

Remove `without dialogs` and it opens as expected.

So, the only work-around for now seems to be ignoring the dialogs parameter.

Hopefully Adobe will either update their AS dictionary or fix the bug.

Take care!

Comment: Can confirm: AI 2020’s `open` command *always* throws a “File Not Found” error when its direct parameter is an *alias* value *and* it has one or more labeled parameters. This **is** an implementation bug in AI’s `aevt/odoc` event handler; the file does exist, so it *should* open. It is not an AI dictionary bug (amusingly enough I did find a dictionary bug, but it’s unrelated), and it’s not a crashing bug so don’t say it is (i.e. AI continues running as normal afterward). See the extra information appended to my original answer (which you’re welcome to include in your bug report to Adobe).

Comment: Thanks, Foo, I sit corrected re: error vs. crash.  Haven't touched the code in question for >5 years so you're probably also right that it's something Adobe has deprecated.  Should refactor everything to posix in my voluminous free time.  ;)